# How to add fade effect when changing wallpaper using c#

Tags: c#, fade, wallpaper

is there a way to add fade effect when changing wallpaper just like on windows 7 using c#?
Any codes or links to article will be appreciated.

Comment: You want to have the same fade effect as when the wallpaper changes backgrounds automatically?

Comment: Good code for changing the wallpaper (but does not address your question about fading) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net/1061682#1061682

Comment: @RCIX -not exactly, just want to know if it is possible to do this in c# and how can it be done.

Answer (score 2):

This forum post covers changing the wallpaper with a fade: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1035559-fade-effect-when-changing-wallpaper/

They use IActiveDesktop, includes a link to the wrapper class.

**Edit**
I've now taken this code, and other code, and have implemented it in an open source project: https://pulse.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72677#1589017

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Create a window behind everything else (except the desktop).
- Paint it with the current wallpaper
- Change the desktop wallpaper
- Fade out the window (increases it's transparency over a second or two)

You'll have to figure out how to get the window in front of the desktop, but behind the explorer icons. (I assume it's possible to do that.)

Comment: yeah, i thought of doing that but i can't get the window in the desktop level.