# Changing Wallpaper with a batch file, on program close. Possible?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, background, wallpaper

I'm trying to create a batch file that will change my background when a program closes on Windows 7. I've tried using this, but it doesn't work, even when I log off and log back in:

```
@echo off
reg /add HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d c:\images\wallpaper.bmp
```

Comment: Are you also opening the program you want to monitor via the batch script?

Answer (score 17):

There are some errors in your command:

1. You have added unnecessarry `/` to `add` command.
2. You don't enclose registry key name in quotes (for space escape).
3. You have specified wrong path (extra `WallPaper` at the end).

This should do the trick:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d c:\images\wallpaper.bmp
```

Of course, if the wallpaper path contains spaces you must enclose it in quotes too.

I also added key `/f` to force overwriting if wallpaper is already set.

Comment: It doesn't actually update the screen, any way to force that to happen?

Comment: @Mr.TA add this line `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10` and run the bat file as administrator - that worked for me.

Comment: @Mr.TA try to add this line to your script after the reg add:

`RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True`

Comment: Unfortunately, on my PC (Windows 10), it writes the path into the Wallpaper key, but nothing happens - JPG image isn't displayed. Also not with the RUNDLL32.EXE hint to update parameters. Who knows what has changed in W10 ? If I change it via context menu (Personalize), then WallPaper gets populated and the image changes.

Comment: **Got the issue:** The script in the answer writes to "Wallpaper" but the value's name actually is **"WallPaper"** - and it is case-sensitive. Now it works!

Comment: ... but it doesn't always update the image immediately. Does anyone know if there is some more reliable command availabe to force update the picture? I am currently looking [here](https://superuser.com/questions/398605/how-to-force-windows-desktop-background-to-update-or-refresh) ...

Comment: And it only works reliably when using bmp's! Convert jpg to bmp before using this.

Comment: LETS GOOOOO, this website gives a PowerShell script that works very amazingly and reliably: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15291

Comment: To run this powershell script you do this: `os.system(f'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "{scriptPath}"')`