# In visual studio C# how can I change the desktop background to an image from my resources

Tags: c#, image, desktop

I am trying to learn C# and I want to know how to make a little program to change the desktop background to an image I embedded in the resources.

Comment: Change the background of what? Your desktop? Your application?

Comment: Look here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414635/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-programatically

Answer (score 2):

**First** get Image from your resource:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(
                   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
                   GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources.myimage.png"));
```

or

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myimage);
```

**Second** Save image to specify Path using [`Image.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).

**Finally** change desktop background using this code from a SO post:

- [Change desktop wallpaper using code in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1061682/1495442)

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting a run time error that says "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Comment: in which level? first second third?