# What is the Windows API for reading/writing desktop pixels?

Tags: windows, desktop

I have done quite a bit of research, to no avail.  I need to find out the Windows API for accessing the image that is being displayed on the Windows desktop at any one time.  I would like to be able to read/write at the pixel level.  (All my Google searches result in links to remote desktop software!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414635/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-programatically?rq=1

Maybe you can access the wallpaper, change it the way you want and set the changed image as new wallpaper

Comment: I have stated in my question that I did do substantial research.  Why the downvote?

Comment: To the person who is responsible for the downvote: please read this guidance relating to downvotes at the Meta SO site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `GetDC(NULL);` to get the device context for the screen. With this you can use `CreateCompatibleDC` to get your own copy and `CreateCompatibleBitmap` Then use `SelectObject` and `BitBlit` to copy the Bitmap to your local Bitmap where you can manipulate it.