# Disabling Desktop Wallpaper

Tags: c#, wallpaper, desktop-wallpaper

does anybody know if there is a way to disable the Desktop Wallpaper image temporarily, and show just the current default "background color" and then enable the desktop wallpaper back again just the way it was?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by **Disable the Desktop Wallpaper** ?

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically, check out this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net

Comment: Yes, I need to do this programmatically, but not setting another Wallpaper, instead I need to just disable it or hide it, if I change it, then I need to remember the previous wallpaper, and I would like to avoid that step @AlexBell

Answer (score 0):

Going into safe mode will show you it.
Otherwise there is no other ways.
And please also only use relative tags.

~Jedi

Comment: Thanks @user3522327, I am using tags related to my question.

Comment: Hello, @AJ152 I did not realize you wanted to it programmatically sorry for the inconvenience.