# Change desktop background in C#

Tags: c#, desktop

I try to change the background using C#.Example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 uiAction, UInt32
    uiParam, String pvParam, UInt32 fWinIni);
    private static UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
    private static UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x1;
```

And then

```
  SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 1, @"C:\background.bmp", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
                            }
```

But it doesn't work...Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change desktop wallpaper using code in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net)

Comment: http://www.scottgames.com/4.bpm does not work for me..

Comment: well it's actually scottgames.com/4.jpg but in my main program I use a .bmp file. Sorry

Comment: so what, you downloaded the image and changed it to bmp? I mean show us the code that you actually use.

Comment: Well it's the address of a private website.It's just an address pointing to a .bmp image, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pvParam` should be a local file. It will not work for urls...

First download the image, then give its local path to `SystemParametersInfo` method.

```
var filename = "4.jpg";
new WebClient().DownloadFile("http://www.scottgames.com/4.jpg", filename);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 1, filename, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work with .bmp images?It also works with JPEG images?

Comment: I tried it before posting. Yes it works also for jpg images