# Change Desktop Wallpaper on only one of my 2 screens in c# code

Tags: c#, desktop-application

So like the title says I want to set the wallpaper on only one of my two screens. I used the code from a diffrent stackoverflow question. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net#1061682).

Thanks for any kind of help :)