# Why I can't use System.Drawing.dll in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am copying the code in this discussion:
[Change desktop wallpaper using code in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061678/change-desktop-wallpaper-using-code-in-net)

But now I have a problem with the System.Drawing reference.
At the line:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
```

I have the following error: the type name 'Image' could not be found in the namespace "System.Drawing".

I right-clicked on project "CambioSfondo" -> Add -> Project Reference -> COM -> searched for System.Drawing.dll and add it, but the error is still there.

Could someone please help me?
[Look my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bOua.png)

Comment: Try System.Drawing.dll exists in Reference  -> Assemblies -> Framework.

Comment: What project type did you create?

Comment: Output Type: Console Application
Target framework: .NET 5.0

Comment: Target .NETFramework instead.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrTbkHDJGtw&ab_channel=LearnC%23
Go at 19:30 this guy view "Assemblies" in the references manager menu but I only see:
Project
Shared Project
COM
Browse

Comment: GDI+ is known for it's slowness and limited capabilities. Unless you're going to work with Windows Forms you shouldn't use System.Drawing. Use alternatives, e.g. SkiaSharp